# Alternatives to LsaLogonUser with KERB_S4U_LOGON have Network access?

Tags: c++, winapi, impersonation, sspi

Are there any alternatives to LsaLogonUser for impersonating given account in order to access network resources? I'm looking for the method of impersonation which would let me call a remote machine via UNC in the same domain.

For initial data I have: domain\username.

I have no password, because this I am using LsaRegisterLogonProcess and LsaLogonUser with Kerberos package. Locally everything is working and I can impersonate and call applications using a different username, however, when trying to access a remote machine using.. \\remotemachine\shared\somefile.bat I have Access Denied.

Basically I call cmd.exe as command.. and then a Console opens with a new user impersonated, but if a Try to call the UNC path, Access Denied.

If I open a basic console with my own user, I execute this UNC path successfully. Is not Folder permissions because is a public Share.

This is a part of my working code:

```
    ...

    NTSTATUS Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    LSA_OPERATIONAL_MODE unused;

    LSA_STRING lsaString;
    lsaString.Buffer = "User Impersonated LogonProcess";
    lsaString.Length = strlen(lsaString.Buffer);
    lsaString.MaximumLength = lsaString.Length + 1;

    Status = LsaRegisterLogonProcess(&lsaString, &lsa, &unused);
    if (Status != STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf("LsaRegisterLogonProcess failed: %x\n", Status);
    }

    ...

    NTSTATUS status = LsaLogonUser(
                                    lsa,
                                    &origin,
                                    Network,
                                    packageId,
                                    authInfo,
                                    authInfoSize,
                                    0,
                                    &source,
                                    &profileBuffer,
                                    &profileBufLen,
                                    &luid,
                                    &token,
                                    &qlimits,
                                    &subStatus
                                );

    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ULONG err = LsaNtStatusToWinError(status);
        printf("LsaLogonUser failed: %x\n", status);
        return 1;
    }

    ...

    DuplicateTokenEx(token, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &tokenDuplicate);

    if (CreateProcessWithTokenW(
                                tokenDuplicate,
                                LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,
                                command,
                                command_arguments,
                                CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                &si,
                                &pi))
            {
                pi.hThread = NULL;
                pi.hProcess = NULL;
                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            }
```

Comment: If you could log into a user account on a remote machine without knowing the password, that would be a serious security vulnerability.  You have admin privileges on your own machine, so you can subvert it so that *it* thinks that you're a particular user, but unless you can somehow also subvert all the *other* machines on the network, they're not going to play along.

Comment: In cases when you have untrust connection to LSA make sense to block network resources for this token, however, in my case I have a trustable connection to perfom LsaLogonUser and then creating a process with LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY that according [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx), access to network resources is possible, but I don't know how and I see no working difference between _WITH_PROFILE or _NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, both are working with denied access to network. The diff. I see is only at the Temp folder created in the Users folder.

Comment: Are you trying to run the program so that it uses the artificial identity locally, but your existing credentials when accessing the network?  Because LOGON_NETCRENTIALS_ONLY does the exact opposite; the code as currently posted tries to use your existing identity locally, but the (missing) network credentials from the artificially generated token.  Why exactly are you messing with the token in the first place?

Comment: Trying to fix this "(missing) network credentials from the artificially generated token".. =(

Comment: You can't do that without the user's password.